# Dust.js template master/detail example

Tags: javascript, templates, client-side, dust.js

I am looking all around and haven't found anything about it.

has anyone being able to create a "master/detail" sample with dust.js template engine?

do you have any jsfiddle with it?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by a "master/detail" sample?

Comment: Lets say we have a list with <li> showing partial information of a record in a json object ie only "name", and when one the <li> is clicked a different dust template gets rendered with all the information of the particular li based on the  id of the li